# bash if condition on git command result

Tags: command-line, git, error-handling

I have the following error due an invalid git command within my shell-script.   `git push blabla master` results in `fatal: 'blabla' does not appear to be a git repository`

I would like to respond to this error message and do stuff if the error appears.
What's a good way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to check if the command failed for any reason at all, or for only that particular reason?

Comment: Actually only for that reason - because I want to let him add the upstream if it isn't configured already. Therefore only mentioned error message would be unambiguous

Comment: Then you should probably just `grep` for that message, presumably after redirecting `stderr`

Answer (score 2):

You could try with something like this:

```
if git push blabla 2>&1 | grep "fatal: 'blabla' does not appear to be a git repository"; then  
  <fatal-case instructions>  
else  
  <successful-execution-case instructions>  
fi
```

Or, if you want to take care of `git` return code:

```
if [[ ! $(git push blabla) ]]; then  
  <fatal-case instructions>  
else 
  <successful-execution-case instructions>
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You can test like this

```
if /usr/bin/git push; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "Not Ok"
fi
```